# python merging several dataframes with dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

The purpose of this code is to scrape a bunch of URLs then extract data tables from each URL.

Turn the tables into pandas data frames, fix the date, and remove the unnecessary columns, rename the columns then finally combine them all into a single unified data frame with date as an index so the data will be sorted by date so the events which happened simultaneously supposed to be in the same row.
The original data before concatenation:

```
Release Date Argentina Economic Activity YoY

0 2018-10-25 21:00:00+02:00                           -1.6%

1 2018-09-26 21:00:00+02:00                           -2.7%

2 2018-08-23 21:00:00+02:00                           -6.7%

3 2018-07-24 21:00:00+02:00                           -5.8%

4 2018-06-26 21:00:00+02:00                           -0.9%

               Release Date Argentina Gross Domestic Product (GDP) YoY

0 2018-09-19 22:00:00+02:00                                      -4.2%

1 2018-06-19 21:00:00+02:00                                       3.6%

2 2018-03-21 21:00:00+02:00                                       3.9%

3 2017-12-20 22:00:00+02:00                                       4.2%

4 2017-09-21 21:00:00+02:00                                       2.7%
```

But what happened after the concatenation is that the different dates are together at the same row so let say that they are 3 tables I will find three dates together in the first row then the second...etc.

Like this:

```
2018-01-24 22:00:00+02:00, 2016-06-29 21:00:00...                            3.9%                                       0.5%

(2018-02-28 22:00:00+02:00, 2016-09-22 21:00:00...                            2.0%                                      -3.4%

(2018-03-28 21:00:00+02:00, 2016-12-22 22:00:00...                            4.1%                                      -3.8%

(2018-04-24 21:00:00+02:00, 2017-03-21 21:00:00...                            5.1%                                      -2.1%
```

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone
import time


class DataEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.urls = open(r"C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\sample.txt").readlines()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Projects\Tutorial\Driver\chromedriver.exe")
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        self.time = time.time()

    def title(self):
        names = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            title = self.driver.title
            names.append(title)
        return names

    def table(self):
        DataFrames = []
        for url in self.urls:
            self.driver.get(url)
            while True:
                try:
                    item = self.wait.until(
                        ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"showMoreHistory")]/a')))
                    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", item)
                except Exception:
                    break

            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Release Date', 'Time', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous'])
            pos = 0
            for table in self.wait.until(
                    ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id,"eventHistoryTable")]//tr'))):
                data = [item.text for item in table.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[self::td]")]
                if data:
                    df.loc[pos] = data[0:5]
                    pos += 1
            df = df.head(10)
            DataFrames.append(df)
        return DataFrames

    def date(self):

        dfs = []
        tables = self.table()
        for df in tables:
            Dates = []
            df["Date"] = df["Release Date"].apply(lambda x: x[:12]) + " " + df["Time"]
            for date in df["Date"]:
                date = datetime.strptime(date.strip(), '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')
                Dates.append(date)
            df["Date"] = Dates
            df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.tz_localize('US/Eastern').dt.tz_convert(get_localzone())
            df = df[['Date', 'Actual', 'Forecast', 'Previous', 'Release Date', 'Time']]
            df = df.drop(df.columns[-4:], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

            dfs.append(df)

        return dfs

    def rename(self):
        FinalDataFrames = []
        tables = self.date()
        names = self.title()
        for name, table in zip(names, tables):
            table.rename(columns={'Date': 'Release Date', 'Actual': name}, inplace=True)
            table['Release Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table['Release Date'])
            FinalDataFrames.append(table)
        return FinalDataFrames

    def update(self):
        dfs = self.rename()
        for df in dfs:
            last_read = df.iloc[0, 0]
            latest_release_date = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="releaseInfo"]/span[1]/div').text
            latest_release_time = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('td.left')[1].text
            latest = latest_release_date + ' ' + latest_release_time
            latest = pd.to_datetime(latest)
            latest_release = latest.tz_localize('US/Eastern').tz_convert(get_localzone())
            if last_read == latest_release:
                pass
            else:
                self.rename()

    def final_df(self):
        self.update()
        while True:
            dfs = self.rename()
            df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, join='outer')
            df = df.set_index('Release Date')
            df = df.sort_index(ascending=True)
            print('fin', time.time() - self.time)
            print(df)
            df.to_csv('FinalDF.csv')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DataEngine().final_df()
```

Comment: Could you show data input and expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you are creating dataframes with numeric indexes that run from 0 on. When you concatenate them along columns (`axis=1`), Pandas merges records with identical index values. You should instead set the date as the index before the concatenation, which will give Pandas the chance to merge records with the same date.

Here is a simplified example. Let's create two dataframes with both dates and some value:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2018-10-01', 3.1],['2018-10-03', 5.5]],
                       columns=['date','growth %'])
>>> df1
         date  growth %
0  2018-10-01       3.1
1  2018-10-03       5.5
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2018-10-01', 100],['2018-10-02', 200]],
                       columns=['date','items'])
>>> df2
         date  items
0  2018-10-01    100
1  2018-10-02    200
```

If we directly concatenate them, Pandas will merge records with identical index values resulting in both having two `dates` columns and the records not being properly aligned on the time axis:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
         date  growth %        date  items
0  2018-10-01       3.1  2018-10-01    100
1  2018-10-03       5.5  2018-10-02    200
```

This is not what you want.

The first step is to transform the `date` column of each dataframe to a datetime object and set it as index:

```
>>> df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
>>> df1 = df1.set_index('date')
>>> df1
            growth %
date                
2018-10-01       3.1
2018-10-03       5.5
>>> df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])
>>> df2 = df2.set_index('date')
>>> df2
            items
date             
2018-10-01    100
2018-10-02    200
```

Concatenation now works as expected:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
            growth %  items
date                       
2018-10-01       3.1  100.0
2018-10-02       NaN  200.0
2018-10-03       5.5    NaN
```

You don't really need to convert the date columns to datetime. It works fine with strings too:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(...)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(...)
>>> pd.concat([df1.set_index('date'), df2.set_index('date')], axis=1)
            growth %  items
2018-10-01       3.1  100.0
2018-10-02       NaN  200.0
2018-10-03       5.5    NaN
```

All that is required is that each dataframe is indexed by date. Datetime indexes though allow slicing and resampling of time series.